# Gradle - Changing "compile" to "implementation" get error

Tags: gradle, groovy, build.gradle

**build.gradle - partly:**

```
    dependencies {
        compile 'org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:2.4.15'
    }
```

If change `compile` to `implementation`, on build will get following error:

> Execution failed for task ':greeter:compileJava

Changing it back then build will succeed.

**Tips:**

- The project is using `Gradle 4.10`, which do support `implementation`.
- There are other dependencies, in the sub projects, change to use `implementation` won't cause issue, only this single line will.

Any help?

Comment: do you have a more verbose error ?

Comment: @ToYonos Yes, please refer to scan link: https://scans.gradle.com/s/rsvkecnl4sfq2/plugins

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was wondering why your main java project would need `groovy-all` as it's used to compile the groovy library. `implementation` configuration should be enough.

I did reproduce your issue and focus on the error thanks to your link :

```
:greeter:compileJava FAILED
/mnt/star/git_repository/workspace/groovy_workplace/gradle/hello/hello_multi_project/greeter/src/main/java/greeter/Greeter.java:5: error: cannot access GroovyObject
        final String output = GreetingFormatter.greeting(args[0]);
                                               ^
  class file for groovy.lang.GroovyObject not found
```

Why is `GroovyObject` needed to compile your java code ? I looked into `GroovyObject` source code and it hit me :

```
package groovy.lang;

/**
 * The interface implemented by all Groovy objects.
 * <p>
 * Especially handy for using Groovy objects when in the Java world.
 *
 * @author <a href="mailto:james@coredevelopers.net">James Strachan</a>
 */
public interface GroovyObject {
[...]
```

> The interface implemented by all Groovy objects. Especially handy for
>   **using Groovy objects when in the Java world**.

`GreetingFormatter` is a Groovy object and implicitly implements `GroovyObject`. That's why `groovy-all` is needed in the compile classpath i.e. it should be declare as a `compile` dependency in the groovy library.

Comment: Actually I was trying multi-projects building via gradle according to this official tutorial: https://guides.gradle.org/creating-multi-project-builds/ , it's using `compile` in the groovy sub project, and the java sub project use that groovy sub project on compiling. I thought `implementation` did the same thing as `compile`, seems they are still different ...

Comment: take a look on this link https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_library_plugin.html#sec:java_library_separation

Comment: After reading, I still don't get when to use `compile`, the link is a bit complex, for now I would just use `compile` for such error cases.

Comment: `implementation` disables transitive dependency and keeps them inside the project

Comment: Ok, I see, but I also tried `api`, it also won't work ... thus seems `compile` is necessary for this case.

Comment: `api` is not a valid configuration for a groovy project

Comment: Ok, I will check the link in more details as need, thanks.

Comment: I can still reproduce this error. On one hand, I see "`compile` is deprecated" message. On the other hand, `implementation` doesn't work in this. case. The tutorial is confusing, what's the recommended solution? Is it ok to just ignore the deprecation message?